# How to change the location of output or the cursor at output, for C++ in "Code Blocks"

Tags: c++

Hi to enthusiasts programming, I use "Code Blocks" ver17.12 on windows10, now want to take the output result to row 10 and column 10, so i used gotoxy() function that the above IDE gave an error.
**Error text** :'gotoxy' was not declared in this scope.
It should be noted that before the main function, I put conio.h

Then I did a google search for syntax gotoxy() to change the location of the output or the cursor at the output, but I did not get a result.
Thank you for guiding me in this regard.

Comment: Hi welcome to SO. Take a minute to read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: What compiler does CodeBlocks use?  The Borland Turbo C++ compiler supports "conio.h," but the GCC compiler doesn't.  Were there no other errors than just the one about gotoxy?  So it found the conio.h file without problems?  Maybe look inside the conio.h file to see if gotoxy is in there.

Comment: conio.h implementation is very platform and compiler dependent. Some compiler/platform may support gotoxy, other not!

Comment: I use a GCC Compiler. I even deleted "conio.h", but it still gave the same error. It only gives one error. I think it's a problem with syntax, but I didn't get any results despite searching on google

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `gotoxy()`. Take a look at this program structure:

```
#include <windows.h>

void gotoxy(int x, int y); // declaration
.
.
void gotoxy(int x, int y) {
    static HANDLE h = NULL;

    if (!h) h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    COORD c = {x, y};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(h, c);
}
```

Alternatively, you can put:

```
#include <windows.h>

void gotoxy(int x, int y) { 
    COORD coord;

    coord.X = x;
    coord.Y = y;
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}
```

**Notes:**

- `#include <windows.h>` must required for both code.
- `conio.h` isn't supported by GCC compiler.
- You didn't need to delete any of the header file.

Comment: I thought like some compilers (if I'm not mistaken, like Borland C ++) by writing "gotoxy(x,y)",it is possible to change the location of the cursor and there is no need to define the function. But with the same code as the alternative above, I got the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @WithinPath Yes, such things are not required in C++ now. They're only available in just some of the rare compilers, I was amazed when I saw that it wasn't working on MinGW, TDM-GCC, GDB-C++.